# Compound Index along with Single Index

Tags: mongodb, indexing, compound-index

I have two fields in a document I want to index. One of them is Receive Time, and the other one is Serial Number. I want users to be able to query on Serial Number alone or on both Serial Number and Receive Time.

The way I see it, I have two options.

A.

`db.collection.ensureIndex({SerialNumber: 1, ReceiveTime: 1})`
`db.collection.ensureIndex({ReceiveTime: 1})`

B.

`db.collection.ensureIndex({ReceiveTime: 1, SerialNumber: 1})`
`db.collection.ensureIndex({SerialNumber: 1})`

Apparently, option A is a better choice (you want fields with low uniqueness to be later on in an index) versus option B. Why is that the case?

However, at the same time the MongoDB documentation states that if your index increments then [the whole index need not fit in RAM](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/ensure-indexes-fit-ram/). If this is a very write heavy application, would B then be the better option? (compound indexes are larger than single indexes and the compound index increments as opposed to A which doesn't increment)

Comment: Because the more selective a first field the more likely the index will be limited down to as few a records as possible, i.e. if you start with a boolean value and then you index by serialNumber, you must search all of that boolean value (true or false) for all serialNumbers, b would not be a better choice since you must still load the entire index to understand what serialnumber to update

Comment: What about the value in Received Time being a field that increments? Is there any merit in using B because of that fact?

Comment: Hmm after some more thinking the index for a compound index is more of a hierachal tree so technically it will only update the latest times serialNumbers, but I am unsure if that will provide a noticable benefit compared with querying

Comment: Come to think of it, time is extremely selective too, with that in mind I would probably go with b

Comment: I have a better idea. You can use the _id field to store a Date so I'm going to use that instead (it is automatically indexed) and so I basically have a free ReceivedTime index (precise to the second). So I eliminate one whole index

Comment: Not really, since MongoDB can still only use one index per query which means when you go to query by the two together you still need an index that contains {_id:1,SerialNumber:1}, also not everything in MongoDB (i.e. aggregation framework) supports using the _id as a timestamp

Comment: Yeah, I still need the compound index but I don't need `db.collection.ensureIndex({ReceiveTime: 1})` any longer. Is there anything glaring about using the _id as a timestamp? I don't think I'll be using the aggregation framework

Comment: Ah yeah true, the only other thing I can think of is if your _ids are not a true representation of when the record was made (i.e. they are made maybe some second before the record is sent to db), but I think yours most likely will be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decision between {SerialNumber: 1, ReceiveTime: 1} and {ReceiveTime: 1, SerialNumber: 1} should be based on the type of queries that you plan to perform. If you generally query for a specific SerialNumber but a large range of possible ReceiveTimes, then you want to use {SerialNumber: 1, ReceiveTime: 1}. Conversely, if your queries are specific for ReceiveTime but more general for SerialNumber then go for {ReceiveTime: 1, SerialNumber: 1}. This way each query is likely to require fewer pages of the index, and will minimize the amount of swapping that the OS has to do.

Similarly, if you are always querying by, say, the most recent ReceiveTimes, then you can keep the working set small by using {ReceiveTime: 1, SerialNumber: 1}. You will only need to keep the pages corresponding to the most recent ReceiveTimes in memory. This is what the documentation you linked to is suggesting.